# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on ArrayList#contains (multithreaded)

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I recently came across an unexpected error (in code that isn't mine) that causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on `ArrayList#contains`. The relevant code here is below.

```
private static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

static void register() {
    update();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            update();
        }
    }, 0, 21600000);
}

private static void update() {
    list.clear();
    new Thread(() -> {
        List<String> other; //should always be the same length.
        list.addAll(other);
    }).start();
}

public static boolean contains(String string) { //called long after register
    return list.contains(string); //throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
}
```

I'm well aware that `ArrayList` is not thread safe and that it can be fixed with something like `Collections#synchronizedList`. My question is to understand how this particular code is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The stacktrace for the exception identifies the following code in `ArrayList#indexOf`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[i])) //here
        return i;
```

It seems to me that this can only happen if `size` is greater than `elementData.length`. To my understanding through, `ArrayList#clear` doesn't actually decrease the length of the backing array. Calls to `addAll` should only be increasing its capacity, and `size` is always updated after the array has been expanded. I don't see how this could ever be in a state where `size` is greater than the capacity of the array.

A particular detail that I noticed is that the delay on the `Timer` is 0, which means `update()` is called twice in quick succession. My best guess is that the `addAll` calls are somehow overlapping, which is leaving the list is some type of mixed invalid state.

If someone could explain what's happening here that would be great!

Comment: Please post the entire method surrounding the for-loop. I can only guess what value `o` and `elementData` represent.

Comment: Per the Java docs: If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

Comment: @DiabolicWords Straight from `ArrayList#indexOf`, as stated. I don't see how that would really affect this though. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l302


@smitty1 Yes, I'm aware. My question is primarily related to *how* this happens, particularly with understanding how multithreading works on a fundamental level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without proper synchronization there are **no guarantees** about what changes from one thread are visible in another thread.

**No guarantees** means it is perfectly valid that if thread A changes `elementData` and `size`, thread B sees:

- none of the changes
- an updated `size`, but the old `elementData`
- an updated `elementData`, but the old `size`
- both updated values, but no updates on the contents of `elementData`

---

As to why this happens (see [Wikipedia:Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) for a short introduction):

In modern computers the main memory is relatively slow, so there are multiple levels of caches between the main memory and the CPU core that executes the current thread.

Thread A may keep updates to `size` and `elementData` in CPU registers or one of the several caches and update the main memory sometime later (and even at different times for those fields) - as long as the correctness of what thread A does is not affected. Since no synchronization happens, multithreaded correctness is of no concern - thread A works as if it is the only thread accessing these fields.

Similarly thread B may keep `size` and `elementData` in CPU registers or in the caches, or it may update one or both from main memory as required (may be the cache line where `size` was kept has been flushed, requiring a reload of `size` from the main memory). Since no synchronization happens, thread B assumes that no other thread changes these fields, therefore cached values are always the same as those in main memory.

Comment: I believe this partially answers the question. Do you have a resource that verifies this and provides more detail explaining how multithreading can mismatch variables from different threads like this?